# memory too high in UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, memory, uinavigationcontroller

i've a navigation controller with several viewController and tableViewController.

I'm using all autorelease objects, the problem is that when i push a new view and i use it, memory from Instrumets increase of a bigger value of memory released when i come back in the navigationController. There's not leak warning, when i return to the view then, memory will not increase again, it's like if was all in cache.

I've tried also using objects own by me, with alloc....and release but the story is the same. Is it normal?

Comment: Use heapshot analysis within the leaks instrument to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

UIViewControllers (or to be exact, views/resources/xibs associated with them) are interesting since iOS will hold on to the resources in memory and unload them as required. This is why often the `dealloc` method will seem like it's never called. However don't worry, if you did proper memory management, your controllers and resources will be freed up as required - if there's a low memory warning sent to your app, all the views that are hidden or have been popped, will be unloaded and dealloc'ed.

Try testing your app again, just like you did before, but this time emulate low memory usage (can be done in simulator from the `Hardware` menu), then see if memory usage drops due to your controllers being freed up by the system